# Input box display dollar amount

Tags: c#, wpf, string, format

I have a buttons numpad and a textblock. Now I want to use this numpad to input dollart amount and display it in textblock. For example, If I press 1234 in order. The textblock should display 12.34.How can I do this in c#? I read lots of example on Internet, but I didn't find any of them match my situation.

```
        <Grid x:Name="Numpad">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--buttons Row-->
        <Button x:Name="popup_ClrBtn" Grid.Row="0" Content="Clear" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="ClrBtn_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="popup_AcptBtn" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Accpet" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <!--Keyboard grid-->
        <!--first row of buttons-->
        <Button x:Name="btn7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="numpad_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="numpad_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="btn9" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="numpad_Click" />
        <!--Second row of buttons-->
        <Button x:Name="btn4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="numpad_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="numpad_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="btn6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="numpad_Click" />
        <!--Third row of buttons-->
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="numpad_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"  Click="numpad_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="btn3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="numpad_Click" />
        <!--Last row of buttons-->
        <Button x:Name="btn0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Times New Roman"  Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="numpad_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn00" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Content="00" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Times New Roman"  Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="numpad_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="CancelBtn" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Times New Roman"  Margin="2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Click="CancelBtn_Click" Background="#FFF70B0B" />
        <Label x:Name="amountlbl" Grid.Row="5">Amount:</Label>
        <TextBlock x:Name="amountTb" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question.  We here at SO would like to help you, but we are *not* a code-writing service.  Once you have attempted to code a solution, edit your post with your code using [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Share the xaml for this screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `TextChanged` event handler to your `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
```

And modify event handler code below as per your need:

```
private bool suppressTextChanged = false;
private void TextBox_TextChanged(Object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int caretIndex = textBox.CaretIndex;
    string text = textBox.Text;
    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(text, out value))
    {
        int insertPos = text.Length - 2;
        if (insertPos > 0)
        {
            text = text.Insert(insertPos, ".");

            suppressTextChanged = true;
            textBox.Text = text;
            if (caretIndex >= insertPos)
                caretIndex++;
            textBox.CaretIndex = caretIndex;
            suppressTextChanged = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I don't think what I said is very clear. The dot should insert before last 2 digit. And by ur solution. It was appendding after first 2 digit.

Comment: @CZA Check my edits, you can always change it as per your need. Answer is just for your guidance and only you know your requirements!

Comment: thanks for helping again. I already find the best solution based on my situation. I can convert it to decimal and divide it by 100, your solution is also valuable!